# A standard Operations on sets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to show the following property of sets:

$$ A \cap ( \bigcup A_{\alpha} ) = \bigcup (A \cap A_{\alpha}) $$

My attempt:

Let $x \in A \cap ( \bigcup A_{\alpha} )$. This occurs iff $x \in A $ or if there is some $\alpha $ with $x \in A_{\alpha} $. How can I conclude from here that there is some $\alpha$ such that $x \in A $ and $x \in A_{\alpha} $ ?

I am stuck at this point. Any help would be grateful. thanks

Comment: You wrote "or" where you meant "and".

Comment: You have your ands and ors confused. x has to be in both sets being intersected. And, not or.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close.  Your first point is slightly off.  If $x \in A \cap \left( \bigcup A_{\alpha} \right)$ then you can say that $x \in A$ AND $x \in A_{\alpha}$ for some $\alpha$.  Thus $x \in A \cap A_{\alpha} \subset \bigcup(A \cap A_{\alpha})$.

Answer (score 1):

Note $x \in A \cap \big(\bigcup A_a \big) \Rightarrow x \in A$ and $x \in \bigcup A_a$.  This implies $x \in A_a$ for some $a$. Then we must have $x \in A \cap A_a$ for some $a$ $\Rightarrow x \in \bigcup \big( A \cap A_a\big)$. Thus $A \cap \big(\bigcup A_a \big) \subset \bigcup \big(A \cap A_a\big)$. The other direction is similar.